# Drop columns from a #temp table based on CSV input parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to drop columns from a SQL Server temp table if exists from a list?

Something like:

```
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
     @cols will have value like [first_name], [last_name], .....
     So @cols = '[first_name], [last_name], .....'
```

Now

```
    ALTER TABLE #my_tables
    DROP COLUMN @cols
```

How to check if `#my_tables` does contain `last_name` or not? If not ignore it instead of throwing error. I still need to drop other columns which are existing in @cols

I think we can do if exists condition on individual columns.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you bothering to drop columns from a #temp table? Just ignore them.

Comment: because i need to append same columns and values from another dynamic pivot values

Comment: So why don't you wait to construct the #temp table until you know what all of the columns will be? Or just name the new columns first_name2, last_name2, etc.? Or avoid a #temp table in the first place? You know that you're going to have a heck of a time consolidating scope, trying to build and change a #temp table while also needing to use dynamic SQL...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with CRAFTY DBA: you should be passing these values in as a table-valued parameter, not as a comma-separated list. But that doesn't really change the problem: you still to generate all of the `DROP COLUMN` commands dynamically, whether the column names are parsed from a CSV using a table-valued function, or pulled from a TVP.

I'll continue with your current requirement of a comma-separated list.

First, create a string splitting function. This is the one I use:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
    (
        @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Delim VARCHAR(255)
    )
    RETURNS TABLE
    AS
        RETURN ( SELECT [Value] FROM 
          ( 
            SELECT 
              [Value] = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, [Number],
              CHARINDEX(@Delim, @List + @Delim, [Number]) - [Number])))
            FROM (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)
              FROM sys.all_objects) AS x
              WHERE Number <= LEN(@List)
              AND SUBSTRING(@Delim + @List, [Number], LEN(@Delim)) = @Delim
          ) AS y
        );
GO
```

Now, create a silly #temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #foo(id INT, x INT);
```

Now, you can declare the list of columns you want to try to delete, create a dynamic SQL statement that checks that they exist before dropping them, and then drops the ones it can:

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @cols = '[first_name], [last_name], [id]';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N'IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tempdb.sys.columns AS c 
   WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(''tempdb..#foo'') 
   AND name = ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(QUOTENAME(s.Value, ''''),']',''),'[','') + ')
  ALTER TABLE #foo DROP COLUMN ' + s.Value + ';' 
FROM dbo.SplitString(@cols, ',') AS s;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

SELECT * FROM #foo; -- this only returns the column x
```

If you run this part of the code again, against the same table, it will run without error. Some errors you might come across are:

- if you try to drop a column that participates in any constraint (default, PK, FK, check, etc).
- if you try to drop the last column in the table.
- if you have columns with really poorly chosen names that somehow bypass all of the protection I've tried to include here.

Comment: Thanks for the clear solution. I think this will work for me for now. My actual situation here is: I have a user table and respective transaction table which stores all the field names which are modified over the time and its's prior data and updated data(I am using trigger here). So what I am trying to do here is get the fields which are modified from transaction tables and rest of the fields from users table and return all the values to geother as output

Comment: If you don't mind I can give you the code what i am trying to do right now. Please help me to write the best efficient store proc. I know I am asking too much but, this will help me for my complete project.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use dynamic SQL; however, watch out for SQL Injection.

I would pass @cols as a parameter to a stored procedure.

The body of the procedure would be below.

```
-- Declare local variables
DECLARE @STMT NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Create the stmt
SET @STMT = 'ALTER TABLE #my_tables DROP COLUMN ' + @cols;

-- Execute the stmt
EXEC sp_executesql @STMT;
```

I would rather pass a Table Value Parameter, but that is just me.

Comment: I am already using a dynamic query, but when @cols contains like [Address] in the list, which does exists in the temp table, then it is throwing error.

Comment: ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN failed because column 'Address' does not exist in table '#my_tables

Comment: @AaronBertrand, my temp table #my_tables does not contain that Address column, but my '@cols' contains that address as one of coma separated field.

Comment: I know, i was not clear in my question. can read my question now? i have updated it.Thanks

Comment: I just posted a quick example on how to take a list of columns and drop it from the table.  Again, I would use a Table Variable Parameter @TVP.  For each column name in the table, create dynamic SQL to check the existence of the column in the table, if it does exist, drop it.  The code from Gavin is specific to #temporary tables# which is your requirement.  Just put the pieces together ...

Answer (score 1):

to examine the columns of a temp table you need to remember that is it stored in the temp db

```
select *
from tempdb.sys.columns
where object_id = object_id('tempdb..#my_tables')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' 
AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' 
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name'
```

It will return whether the column exists or not, use the response from this SQL to decide whether or not do preform the drop